# How to Install debian package within ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, live-cd, debian

I would like to install my project (deb package) with Ubuntu installation.

I have seen some of the deb packages in Ubuntu source code, but I couldn't find out from where and how they would be installed.

Moreover, I would like to know how Ubuntu is installing default packages like OpenOffice, Python, Firefox etc. within it's installation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? It's not a trivial process. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Also, it is not automatic, as can seems from some answer, that a Debian package install without problems on Ubuntu. It may have (or not) dependencies problems, for example.

Comment: @user606723, enzotib : yes, it have dependancy and you are right it's not easy process, but it's the project need.
I've to create an installer. that could install ubuntu and my package within single installation, like default packages such as python, openoffice, firefox etc.. (instead of any manual install after ubuntu installation).
looking for guidance in correct direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just double click and the deb package and click install. Ubuntu uses the same package format and system. (In fact, Ubuntu is based off Debian. It just has some of it's own changes added). The difference is that some of the packages are slightly modified. Also, Ubuntu has their own repository servers to serve the modified versions of the packages.

So, the packages like OpenOffice would be installed after being downloaded from Ubuntu's package repository servers. They would be installed using the same methods Debian's package management system uses to install Debian's packages.

Comment: thanks for quick response, but I think you are also explaining for, after ubuntu installation process. but I would like to install my project with Ubuntu installation process (dynamically) not after installing Ubuntu.
let me correct. If I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of useful references

1. [Ubuntu Installing Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware) help page
2. Wikipedia **[dpkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg)** page

From the Wikipedia reference,

> To install a .deb package:
>
> **dpkg -i debFileName**
>
> where *debFileName* is the name of the Debian software package.

Comment: thanks for quick response, but I think you misunderstood the question. I would like to install my project with Ubuntu installation process (dynamically) not after installing Ubuntu.